# How to build login system in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, authentication, session, codeigniter-4

I want to build a login system using Codeigniter 4.
But I face some error.

I have some data in `Users_model`;

[image]

Here is my some codes:

***Controller/Signin.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\models\Users_model;

class Signin extends BaseController {

    public function index() {
        return view('signin/index');
    }

    public function authenticate() {
        if ($this->exists($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']) != NULL) {
            $session = session();
            $session->set('email', $_POST['email']);
            return $this->response->redirect(site_url('signin/profile'));
        } else {
            $data['msg'] = 'wrong';
            return view('signin', $data);
        }
    }

    public function profile() {
        return view('signin/profile');
    }

    private function exists($email, $password) {
        $model = new Users_model();
        $account = $model->where('email', $email)->first();
        if ($account != NULL) {
            if (password_verify($password, $account['password'])) {
                return $account;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

***Models/Users_model.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class Users_model extends Model {

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'];

}
```

But I face this error:

[image]

Please help me.

***Or please someone suggest me a login system in another way in Codeigniter 4?***

Comment: From your views it appears that you have a folder called signin. So I am guessing your line: return view('signin', $data); requires a filename, like all the others.

Comment: Hmm you are right. 
I have a folder in `app\Views\signin\profile.php`.
If email password is correct then go to the profile page.
Please help have any bug here. I can't find this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make login system, I suggest you to use `validation` to make user is valid and redirect to another controller or view. Then you can use `filter` to check that user is logged in or not and adding some `routes` filter to protect other controller.
First read this Codeigniter 4.0.4 documentation https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html

You could search anything you need there.

Answer (score 0):

return view('signin', $data);

for

return view('signin/index', $data);

Comment: It would be more beneficial to add some descriptions that what's the issue the OP is facing and how your solution will help them. Please take a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)